# Reading in column with both character and numeric with percent sign

Tags: sas

We're trying to read in a column from a csv that has mainly values of the format 39.9% but also has some values as 's'. We don't believe we can read this column in cleanly with an informat. Is there a way to do this cleanly or will we need to input it as character strings first?

Comment: First I would create a STAGE (TEMP) Dataset importing the value AS IS from the CSV file.  Then, on my final dataset, execute data management statements that allows me to either get rid of the 'S' or give significant value to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you want the data to have.  If the "S" has a meaning of "SKIP" or something like that, where you want it to be a missing value, and otherwise get a numeric result, you can do this two ways.

First off, you can read it with the PERCENTw.d informat, and include `??` to tell the parser not to 
worry about invalid data - automatically make it missing.

```
data test;
  infile datalines truncover;
  input x ??percent9.3;
datalines;
BLANK
39.4%
38.3%
DUMMY
S
IDONTKNOW
49.5%
;;;;
run;
```

Here all nonnumeric values will become `.`.

Second, if you have several different character values and they're always single alphabet characters, you can read them in as special missing.  SAS doesn't just have one missing/null, but 28; `.`, `.A` through `.Z`, and `._`.  You can use the `missing` statement to define particular letters in the input as missing.

```
missing s d r; *skip, don't know, refuse;
data test;
  infile datalines truncover;
  input x percent9.3;
datalines;
37.5%
38.3%
S
49.3%
D
R
R
18.4%
;;;;
run;
missing;
```

The data will show S, D, R in the dataset when you open it up; those values are missing values and won't be used in calculations for `proc means` and such, but are differentiatable.  You can use `if missing(x) then ...` type syntax to determine if x is missing (`if x=.` will not work as none of those values are `.`).  This only works with single characters.  You can combine it with the `??` method if you wish (then anything not in the `missing` statement will become regular `.` missing).

You can clear the treatment of these letters as missing with `missing;` as shown above, otherwise it will persist for your session.

Comment: Upvoted for mentioning the `missing` statement - didn't know about that one!